# SOA: How to fan-in with unknown number of processes

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, soa

In my event-driven architecture I have a situation where once an event is raised validation needs to occur and I'm wondering how to proceed to the next step in the process if I don't know how many validators there might be.

This situation occurs because the users of the software can dynamically extend the domain model with new attributes and validators.

One option is to have all validators register their interest on startup. This would be a nice solution but could potentially introduce race conditions and it requires a centralised list of validators in an architecture that values decentralisation.

Another solution is to not have validators at all. Instead, we could let the process continue as far as possible and wait on further input when it cannot continue because of invalid or missing data. This has the benefit of avoiding the fan-in completely. The problem with this solution is that the process could be quite long-running and maybe the person filling in the initial data for the genesis event might not be available to provide the missing information later in the process.

Are there other, perhaps more elegant, solutions I'm missing?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Are you building a library and the users are software developers?

Comment: I'm building a platform, and the users are the end clients. The platform has some base functionality, but the end clients are the engineers working for the people who buy the software. We can't expect the clients to understand event-driven development or DDD, so we provide a platform that abstracts that complexity and lets them just build standard REST services.

Comment: "potentially introduce race conditions and it requires a centralised list of validators in an architecture that values decentralisation." You are asserting some things here that aren't necessarily true, at least not at a high-level.  Can you elaborate on what problems you see here?